# Using OpenXML to replace text in the document

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I open document and copy to the stream.

How I can replace some text in document before stream?

```
//wordTemplate  - var with path to my word template
byte[] result = null;
byte[] templateBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(wordTemplate);
using (MemoryStream templateStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    templateStream.Write(templateBytes, 0, (int)templateBytes.Length);
    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(templateStream, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

        mainPart.Document.Save();
        templateStream.Position = 0;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            templateStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            result = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this helpful? .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744660/find-and-replace-text-in-xml-file-using-c-sharp

Comment: the target - open word document, change some strings and send for downloading for users

Comment: You can simply use a `Regex` to replace text.  Feed it a `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` of the `WordprocessingDocument`, and voila!  Note: You'd need to rewrite most of this... as it seems like you're not approaching it the easiest way, to start with.

Comment: thanks, please could you provide a short example how to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling File.ReadAllBytes(), why not call [File.ReadAllLines(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) instead? It gives you an array of strings, which you can then can search and replace to your hearts delight.

Comment: I open document in docx format, and how ReadAllLines can help me to replace strings in Word document?